# Updating user contact sharing preference via Google Provisioning API

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client

Is it possible to update a single users contact sharing preference for our organization via any of the Google Provisioning APIs?  We have users that do not not want their contact information shared.  This link, from almost three years ago, is all I could find:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-apps-manager/4z-KmCEbX0k

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Now, users are managed using the Directory API. Do not use the Profiles API or Provisioning API.

To change the contact sharing preference, just set the `includeInGlobalAddressList` property of the user to `false`.

Here is the API documentation : https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users